# How do I fix the error below that I get when I try to update Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: gnupg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

This website wouldn't let me post the links so I replaced them with (LINK).  Which is kind of stupid because I would have liked to copy exactly what I am seeing.  Anyway here is what I get:

```
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: (LINK) oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: (LINK) oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: (LINK) oneiric-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: (LINK) oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: (LINK) oneiric-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: (LINK) oneiric-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch (LINK)  
W: Failed to fetch (LINK)  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```